# CRM 2013 Retrieve all teams for a given user using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to retrieve all teams a user belongs to using LINQ and early bound entities. What am I doing wrong here.

I am passing in the SystemUser user as a parameter to the function

```
var teams = (from teamList in crmContext.CreateQuery<Team>() 
             join mapping in crmContext.CreateQuery<TeamMembership>() 
                    on teamList.Id equals mapping.TeamId 
             join users in crmContext.CreateQuery<SystemUser>() 
                    on user.Id equals users.Id 
             select teamList
             ).ToList();
```

As far as I understood, I am first returning all teams and then joining to get the teams which have a membership and finally where the membership with users where a given user's Id is matched.

It fails with the following error `Sequence contains no matching element`. I have this on the disassociate message which fires a team is removed from a user.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I have also attempted this.

```
var allteams = (from users in crmContext.CreateQuery<SystemUser>() where users.Id == user.Id join mapping in crmContext.CreateQuery<TeamMembership>() on users.Id equals mapping.SystemUserId join teams in crmContext.CreateQuery<Team>() on mapping.TeamId equals teams.Id select teams).ToList();
```

but, I get this message.

> The method 'Join' cannot follow the method 'Where' or is not
>   supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call
>   the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported
>   methods.

I trust that it is because of the LINQ provider for CRM 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your second attempt, try to move the `where` clause to the end just before `select` clause :

```
var allteams = (from users in crmContext.CreateQuery<SystemUser>() 
                join mapping in crmContext.CreateQuery<TeamMembership>() 
                    on users.Id equals mapping.SystemUserId 
                join teams in crmContext.CreateQuery<Team>() 
                    on mapping.TeamId equals teams.Id 
                where users.Id == user.Id 
                select teams
                ).ToList();
```